# How to get buffer type in vimscript

Tags: vim

How can I get the buffer type of a buffer given its buffer id? I know I can switch to that buffer and use `:set buftype?` to get the type.

But how can I do it without jumping to that buffer?

(I would expect to have something like `buftype(id)` working similarly to `bufname(id)`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [`:h getbufvar()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getbufvar%28%29)

```
:echo getbufvar(bufid, '&buftype', 'ERROR')
```

Comment: How to get buffer type of current buffer without know its `bufid`?

Comment: @Rainning, for current buffer you can simply use `&buftype`